# Python if code assistance

Tags: python, csv

I need some assitance in getting some Python code to work correctly.  I have a CSV file that has a number of rows and columns.  What I need to accomplish is use Python to look in column 2 for "iboxhy*".  If this information is found, then in the same row, I need to change the information in columns 7, 9, and 10 to read "INDEXTRS".  I am very new to using Python, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far, but it is not working (returns IndexError: list index out of range):

```
import csv
file = open('test1218.csv')
file_new = open('test1218_2.csv', 'w')
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(file_new, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    if "iboxhy*" in row[2]:
        # CHANGE TO INDEXTRS
        row[10] = "INDEXTRS" # row K
        row[9] = "INDEXTRS" # row J
        row[7] = "INDEXTRS" # row H
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: And what is `row` when the `IndexError` is raised? Try: `try: (if block) except IndexError: print row`. This has to be intended, of course: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Sounds like your input file has a short row in it. Maybe a stray quote mark is swallowing up commas?

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have a sample of your input data so we could help more.

However, I think you may have overlooked the fact that we are dealing with a 0 indexed file as far as columns go... so "Column 2" is actually row[1].

```
import csv
file = open('test1218.csv')
file_new = open('test1218_2.csv', 'w')
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(file_new, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    if "iboxhy*" in row[1]:
        # CHANGE TO INDEXTRS
        row[10] = "INDEXTRS" # row K
        row[9] = "INDEXTRS" # row J
        row[7] = "INDEXTRS" # row H
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I think the 1-based indexes are the issue.

Comment: I have the correct numbering for the rows (columns).  Column 3, which I have in my code as row[2], is where the script looks for the "iboxhy*" text.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `row` is a 0-indexed array. That means that the first column is at index `0`. Hence, the second column is really `1`, your Column H is `6`, etc.

Comment: Oops, beat to the punch by @Jkdc, who has a more complete answer :)

Comment: Okay good. My guess is that maybe there is a row in your CSV that doesn't have 11 columns. I would double-check the csv file as the next step

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the 0-index answer already given, the csv reader returns empty rows when it encounters empty lines in the input file. If you have empty lines at the end of the csv file, you'll hit this problem.

If you want to be really forgiving of the input, you can catch and handle the exception:

```
for row in reader:
    try:
        if "iboxhy*" in row[1]:
            # CHANGE TO INDEXTRS
            row[10] = "INDEXTRS" # row K
            row[9] = "INDEXTRS" # row J
            row[7] = "INDEXTRS" # row H
    except IndexError:
        pass
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: When I enter the code to catch and handle the exception, I get: "There's an error in your program: invalid syntax" and except is highlighted.

Comment: There must have been a minor mistake in the code. My bet is there is something wrong with the line directly above (a missing paren or something). One trick is to add a print statement to the end of the indented block just above the `except` to see if the syntax error moves up to the print. You could post your new code on the bottom of your question and then leave another note here so I am notified and can take a look... or just write a new question completely.